# How to move position of UISlider based on value

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

Is there any way I can move the position of UISlider based on giving _slider.value some value ?

I have basically 2 effects. Brightness and Sepia, which can be controlled with a common UISlider.

The problem is, if I select Brightness and move the UISlider upto max position on right, and then select the Sepia filter, there is no way to increase it. If I move the slider left, the sepia value decreases.

So what I want is, as soon as I change from Brightness to Sepia or otherwise, the slider should come to it's default position.

Got the solution:

I was trying to do

```
 _slider.Value=1.0, which wasn't working.
```

This thing worked:

```
[_sliderValue setValue:0.5];
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a new slider

```
-(IBAction)mySlider
{ 
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 10.0);
    UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [slider setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    slider.minimumValue = 0.0;
    slider.maximumValue = 1.0;
    slider.continuous = YES;
    slider.value = 1.0;
    [self.view addSubview:slider];
}
```

2.For Slider Actions

```
-(void)sliderAction:(id)sender
{
    float value = [sender floatValue];
    //-- Do your actions here
}
```

Comment: Isn't there any way, I can programmatically give the current slider a value, and it's cursor moves?

Comment: @rbk, yes, that's what "slider.value = 25.0;" does.

Comment: It changes the value internally, but in the User Interface, it's still stuck at the last position.

Comment: @rbk are you sure you have correctly bound the slider in your Interface Builder (.xib) to the slider variable you're looking at? because if you had, then setting the value would move the thumb visually.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by bound. I'm using the storyboard, and yeah...the slider does work because I'm able to apply effects based on the movement of the slider.

Comment: @rbk, bound means, do you have an IBOutlet to your slider, and is it connected? You need to use that outlet name when you set the value (as in myOutletName.value = 47).

Comment: interface
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *sliderValue;

implementation
- (IBAction)slidermove:(id)sender {
 _sliderValue.value=1.0;    
}

Is this the way you mean to set it? 

And yeah, it is connected.

Comment: Got it... I was doing _sliderValue.value=1.0

But this thing worked:
[_sliderValue setValue:1.0];

Answer (score 0):

Set audio slider value like this:

```
[audioSlider setValue:sender.value animated:YES];
```

In sliderAction method